# CSS: display:table-cell IE7+ or force floated divs in one row

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The problem is, that i need to force all divs to be in one line. To have table-cell behavior.
**And to support IE7.**

Link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Beck/BH5WG/
And ofc copy of code below:

Html:

```
<div class="wr">
    <div class="con">
        <div class="item">some text1</div>
        <div class="item">some text1 some text1</div>
        <div class="item">some text1</div>
        <div class="item">some text1 some text1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wr" id="wr2">
    <div class="con">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="item">some text1</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="item">some text1 some text1</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="item">some text1</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <div class="item">some text1 some text1</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.wr {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.con {
    height:24px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#wr2 {
    margin:50px 0px 0px 0px;
}


​
```

Comment: One fix would be like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Beck/BH5WG/2/ but it's very big performance issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have my IE7 test environment to hand but have you tried `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left`?

IE7 doesn't understand that by default, but it does understand `display:inline; zoom:1;`

This might make it more willing to comply with `white-space:nowrap;`

For example, from your fiddle:

```
.wr {
    border:1px solid red;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.con {
    height:24px;
}

.item {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
}

#wr2 {
    margin:50px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`display: table` emulation for IE6/7](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/) to have exactly tably presentation in IE6/7. CSS will look like this:

```css
/* Bind htc behavior to element that should behave like table. */
.con {behavior: url(/js/display-table.min.htc); }
```

or this:

```css
/* Bind htc to BODY and then trigger tably behavior via -dt-display property. */
BODY {behavior: url(/js/display-table.min.htc); }
.con {-dt-display: table; }
.item {-dt-display: table-cell; }
```